# Repeat row based on quarter except with change of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, repeat

I would like to repeat the same rows based on the QTR info, but only change the QTR column on each successive row only as long as the QTR is not the current quarter. For example I have a dataset,

```
A = np.random.randint(10, size=(4,5))
df = pd.DataFrame(A)
df['QTR'] = ['2021Q4','2021Q3', '2022Q1','2022Q2']
df
```

I would like to get three row with the column QTR: '2021Q4', '2022Q1', '2022Q2' for the first row where other column values remains same, and so on for the other rows. I am a newbie in python, not sure how to proceed for it? The expected output would be like

```
A1 = np.array([[8,1,6],[8,1,6], [8,1,6], [4,5,2], [4,5,2], [4,5,2], [4,5,2], [8,4,0],[8,4,0], [3,4,7]])
A1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(A1)
df1['QTR'] = ['2021Q4', '2022Q1', '2022Q2', '2021Q3', '2021Q4', '2022Q1', '2022Q2', '2022Q1','2022Q2', '2022Q2']
df1
```

Comment: What is the explicit expected output?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use:

```
(df
 .assign(QTR=df['QTR'].apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x, freq='Q', periods=3).to_period('Q')))
 .explode('QTR')
)
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4     QTR
0  7  7  4  0  8  2021Q4
0  7  7  4  0  8  2022Q1
0  7  7  4  0  8  2022Q2
1  2  5  7  8  9  2021Q3
1  2  5  7  8  9  2021Q4
1  2  5  7  8  9  2022Q1
2  9  9  6  9  3  2022Q1
2  9  9  6  9  3  2022Q2
2  9  9  6  9  3  2022Q3
3  1  8  9  3  4  2022Q2
3  1  8  9  3  4  2022Q3
3  1  8  9  3  4  2022Q4
```

Comment: It doesn't give the data until a certain quarter? It actually drive from the origin quarter to 3 periods. I want it to be until a particular quarter(for example 2022Q2 or 2022Q4 no matter how long before the original quarter. For example if the original Q is 2018Q2, I want to get all quarter until 2022Q4, but if the data is from 2022Q4, I don't want to repeat the rows as the origin is the last quarter I want.

Comment: Still not fully clear, but you might want to provide the stop point instead of the periods in `date_range`, check the docs, give it a try